# Unable to hash passwords with "bcryptjs" -> Console "Error: Illegal arguments: number, string"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I´m having an issue while hashing users passwords in the backend using bcryptjs in a Node/Express Server. When I try to use it following the official documentation I receive the above error. I've tried different ways without any solution. Please could you give me some ideas?

This is the hashing code

```
        const Usuario = require('../models/Usuario');
        const bcryptjs = require('bcryptjs');

        usuario = new Usuario(req.body);

        //Hashear Password
        const salt = await bcryptjs.genSalt(10);
        usuario.password = await bcryptjs.hash(password, salt);

        //Guardar Usuario
        await usuario.save();
        //Mensaje Confirmacion
        res.json({ msg: 'El usuario fue creado correctamente' });
```

And this is the users model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const UsuariosSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    nombre: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true,
        unique: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    },
    registro: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now()
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Usuario', UsuariosSchema);
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the variable `password` passed to bcryptjs.hash must be string type as per their docs.

As in your above given snipped, couldn't identity where and when password is declare and its type.

i tried the below code and got error "illegal Argument: number, string"

```
var password = 1234;
const salt = await bcryptjs.genSalt(10);
var pass= await bcryptjs.hash(password, salt);
```

wherein the below code worked

```
var password = "1234";
const salt = await bcryptjs.genSalt(10);
var pass= await bcryptjs.hash(password, salt);
console.log(pass);
```

Output:
[image]

Can you check on the type value passed to the hash function.